# how to get a value from a Sharepoint list with javascript

Tags: development, javascript, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have the following code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var setTime = // i dont know what to do here
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * setTime;
        display = document.querySelector('#timer2');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

What I want is var `setTime` to get the value or retrieve from list with column named `testval` the datatype for `testval` is number.

Comment: For **SP13**, how to get items from list http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference snippet below  for getting list value through JSOM

```
function retrieveListItems() {
        targetList = list.getByTitle("your list name"); //get the list details
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); //initiate the query object
        camlQuery.set_viewXml(
        '<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/>' +
        '<Value Type=\'Text\'>V</Value></Contains></Where></Query>' +
        '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
     );
        itemColl = targetList.getItems(camlQuery);
        //returns the item collectionbased on the query
        context.load(itemColl);
        context.executeQueryAsync(retrieveListItemsSuccess, retrieveListItemsFail);
    }

function retrieveListItemsSuccess() {
var listItemEnumerator = itemColl.getEnumerator();
 while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
 var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
 var listDetails =oListItem.get_item('Title') ;
 }

 }
 // This function is executed if the above call fails
 function retrieveListItemsFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get list items. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do it also most of the time with REST (ajax) like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Rest URL
        var requestUri = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items";

            $.ajax({
                url: requestUri,
                type: "GET",
                headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data.d.results, function (i, item){
                        var title = item.Title;

                        // Do something                     

                    })
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Something went wrong");
                }                     
            });                    
    });

</script>
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can use rest api to get this

make a request to this page, it will return items in the list

```
http://somesharepointsite/sites/viewstyle/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Employee List')/items?$select=To/Title,To/ID&$expand=To"
```

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: you can make an ajax call and get the data